# Printing an object as a unique string, possibly using its address

Tags: common-lisp, identity, clos

I need a way to create GraphViz node names from CLOS objects in such a way that each object gets its own node, and if I alter my objects and re-create the GraphViz visualization, I get the same node names for objects that stay (referentially) the same.

If I just try printing my object, I get something that is almost good (since I never override `PRINT-OBJECT` for my class):

```
CL-USER> (format nil "~A" *g*)
"#<GREF {1002D22C81}>"
```

Is there a way to get just that `1002D22C81` part as a string? I could then create GraphViz node names like `N1002D22C81` from that.

Or should I just process the result of `(format nil "~A" obj)` as a string by grabbing the part between `{}`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The hex number is the object address. It can *change* after a garbage collection. Your implementation may provide a function to get it directly, but I don't think you should use it.

What you might consider doing is adding a `name` slot to your objects and automatically initializing them using, say, [`gensym`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_gensym.htm).

If you want to keep track of all your objects, you might even [`intern`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_intern.htm) the names in a special package and set their [`symbol-value`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_symb_5.htm) to the objects (**beware** that this will make the objects **uncollectable** by the GC until you [`unintern`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_uninte.htm) their names, or unset their `symbol-value`, or [delete the aforementioned special package](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_del_pk.htm)).

PS. You can get the object address even if you override `print-object` - just pass `:identity t` to [`print-unreadable-object`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_pr_unr.htm).

PPS. I am sure you know that `(format nil "~A" x)` is the same as `(princ-to-string x)`.

Comment: It's (probably) cheaper to create a hash table, then use `(setf (gethash (name node) *node-table*) node)` (or whatever the accessor and table is called).

Comment: @Vatine: `symbol-value` is just a slot access; it is definitely cheaper than hash-table search.

Comment: Symbol interning is not cheap, though. And looking up the symbol by name (a la `find-symbol`) is no cheaper than a hashtable search.

Comment: @Vatine: You are right on both counts. However, my assumption here is that both `intern` and `find-symbol` would be rare in this setting because, first, creation is more rare than access, and, second, the user will keep names as symbols, not as strings. Also, package operations may be more optimized than general hash tables.

Comment: Yes, some benchmarking would be required to find out what the exact performance cost is, for either option. Based on the fact that "alter" was mentioned in the question, I suspect object creation is not infrequent.